# BigQuery Resources exceeded with rank() analytical function

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm encountering the Resources Exceeded error, although my table and query are not that large.

```
Table size = ~4M rows!
Query will process = ~1GB!
```

The query looks like this:

```
select <*~20 columns*>, rank() over (partition by date order by     
sys_create_timestamp desc,file_id desc) as rank_field
from MyTable
WHERE lower(Record_Type) IN ('*opt1*','*opt2*')


JobId = snappy-nature-151915:bquijob_3b087361_15903d2280a
```

Thanks for any help...

Comment: It looks like the issue is coming from memory exceeded in the order by operator. This means that the partition that we are sorting is too large. Could there be a skew in the data causing there to be a date value that is very large (relative to the other ones). This would explain the partition being too large to fit in memory.